# can make aframe scene with multiple 3d model in one canvas that link with javascript?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr, 3d-model

i want to make webVR like http://accessmars.withgoogle.com/ but i'm stuck with how to load scene with multiple 3d model that link each other (like we click or use cursor then go to other scene). 
My code in https://github.com/rinahafizhah/earth-webvr
How do I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski i think point no.1.. i tried making a scene but i have 3 models that i want to include this in my scene..I want when i clicking a plane, that goes to 1 model, as well as the other models. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try the link component:

`<a-gltf-model link="href: anotherscene.html; on: click; visualAspectEnabled: false"></a-gltf-model>`

If you want to go to different part of scene, change camera wrapper position:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('transporter', {
  schema: {
    on: {type: 'string'},
    position: {type: 'vec3'},
  },

  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener(this.data.on, () => {
      this.el.sceneEl.camera.el.parentNode.object3D.position.copy(this.data.position);
    });
  }
});
```

Then:

```
<a-gltf-model transporter="on: click; position: 10 0 -10"></a-gltf-model>

<a-entity id="cameraRig">
  <a-camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-camera>
</a-entity>
```